# Fastest Way to Write Data To Individual Machines?

Tags: python, linux

I have a network of 100 machines, all running Ubuntu Linux.

On a continuous (streaming) basis, machine `X` is 'fed' with some real-time data. I need to write a python script that would get the data as input, load it in-memory, process it, and then save it to disk.

It's a lot of data, hence, I would ideally want to split the data in memory (using some logic) and just send pieces of it to each individual computer, in the fastest possible way. each individual computer will accept its piece of data, handle it and write it to its local disk.

Suppose I have a container of data in Python (be it a list, a dictionary etc), already processed and split to pieces. What is the fastest way to send each 'piece' of data to each individual machine?

Comment: Have you ever read up on MapReduce? It's whole purpose is exactly this. Unfortunately I can't give you a python-specific answer. But I think reading up on this would help you a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two (classes of) choices:

1. You could build some distribution mechanism yourself.
2. You could use an existing tool to handle the distribution and storage.

In the simplest case, you write a program on each machine in your network that simply listens, processes and writes. You distribute from X to each machine in your pool round-robin. But, you might want to address higher-level concerns like handling node failures or dealing with requests that take longer to process than others, adding new nodes to the system, etc.

As you want more functionality, you'll probably want to find some existing tool to help you.  It sounds like you might want to investigate some combinations of AMQP (for reliable messaging), Hadoop (for distributed data processing) or more complete NoSQL solutions like Cassandra or Riak.  By leveraging these tools, your system will be significantly more robust than what you could probably build out yourself.

Comment: what if I already have some code to do the writing on the remote machines; and I just need a method to 'send' the data to the remote machines; wouldn't `ssh-ing` be a good solution as well?

Comment: You could use `ssh`, which would incur certain overheads (e.g., key negotiation, encryption) while providing certain functionality (e.g., verify connection to particular host, wire-level confidentiality).  If you don't care about crypto, look at the SocketServer python module for the server side.  Still, this "class 1" approach doesn't deal with things like hosts that are down, load balancing, etc. Which, you may not care about.

Comment: thank you. You are right the `ssh` has some overhead. but what if I initialize all connections at first (it takes few seconds), and when connected, keep writing data to the remote nodes? will I still have a lot of overhead in your opinion?

Comment: The encryption overhead on machines at runtime is probably negligible.

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at `pyzmq`:

http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:python

and general guides to zeromq (0mq)

http://nichol.as/zeromq-an-introduction

http://www.zeromq.org/

Comment: can you explain what makes this better than simply (programatically) `ssh-ing` to the machine and send the data there?

Comment: @user540009: Because 0mq provides a number of different connection types and interaction patterns and is likely much faster for distributing the data chunks than ssh. It also supports both pickling and json serialization to move python objects around a network. You asked for the "fastest way" to distribute the data, and 0mq is very fast. Beyond that, I don't know enough about what you want to do and the constraints to offer more than a suggestion of a technology to consider.

Comment: thank you. will `0mq` also allow me to run programs on the remote machines? or will it just send messages? also, it appears that with `0mq` the remote machine has to 'listen' to the incoming message, whereas with `ssh` I can just connect to the remote machine and 'instruct it' what to do.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a message queue like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com). It is easy to add consumers and producers to a queue. Consumer can either poll or get notified through a callback...

Comment: can you explain what makes this better than simply (programatically) `ssh-ing` to the machine and send the data there?